# creating XML to XSD specification in oracle database

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-ords, mod-plsql

Is there a practical way that I can generate XML data in the oracle database (stored in normal relational tables not in objects) which matches a XSD specification?

Its a complicated specification involving data implemented in a large number of oracle tables - I don't want  to have to write pages of complicated SQL with XMLForrest and XMLElement etc.

If there is can someone give a link to oracle documentation or a book I can buy or some other resource where I can learn how to do this?

If it cannot be done in the database is there some other recommended practice for doing this?